# Python: Change class variable with method from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import

I want to change class dictionary in main file with a method from another file. When I call the method it acts like it did it's job, yet when dictionary is called from the main file again, it looses the appended entry.

Main file, **testmain.py**:

```
import testside


class MainClass(object):
    objects = {'three': 'four'}


if __name__ == '__main__':

    testside.SideClass.add_to('one', 'two') # prints {'three': 'four', 'one': 'two'}
    print(MainClass.objects)                # prints {'three': 'four'}
```

Side file, **testside.py**:

```
import testmain


class SideClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def add_to(name, thing):
        testmain.MainClass.objects[name] = thing
        print(testmain.MainClass.objects)
```

What can I do to change class value from outside the file? Note, that I don't want to create an instance of `MainClass()`.

Comment: this example should not ever work, as your are creating a cyclic import

Comment: Thanks, I worry a lot about cyclic imports, yet I haven't found a good read about how to avoid them. Do you have anything to recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SideClass is importing its own copy of the MainClass class.  You need to pass in the copy you want to change (even though it isn't an instance!) because MainClass has already been read in its own file.

This works:
Main file, **testmain.py**:

```
import testside

class MainClass(object):
    objects = {'three': 'four'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testside.SideClass.add_to(MainClass, 'one', 'two') # prints {'three': 'four', 'one': 'two'}
    print(MainClass.objects)                # prints {'three': 'four', 'one': 'two'}
```

Side file, **testside.py**:

```
class SideClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def add_to(cls, name, thing):
        cls.objects[name] = thing
        print(cls.objects)
```

As a bonus, you no longer need to import MainClass in SideClass, and can dynamically use SideClass for any class you want.

I feel compelled to ask though, why do you want to do this?  The question reeks of X-Y problem.

Comment: I need to create dictionary with a list of objects. I need them to be easily accessed from anywhere (anyfile?) by name, so I figured the easiest way would be to create a dictionary in the main file of the program.